# CSS div overflow:auto does not work

Tags: html, css

My div-overflow is not working.

LINK:   [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gp4L/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="modalDialog" id="chooseVariableDialog">
     <h4>Choose Variables</h4>

  <div class="" id="variablesContainer">
    <div class="variablesDiv">
        <div class="variablesType">Variables</div>
    </div>
    <div class="variablesDiv">
        <div class="variablesType">Type</div>
    </div>
    <div class="variablesDiv">
        <div class="variablesType">comp1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="variablesDiv">
        <div class="variablesType">extern1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="variablesDiv">
        <div class="variablesType">coord1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="variablesDiv">
        <div class="variablesType">id1</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  div.variablesDiv {
   float: left;
   width: 150px;
   align-content: center;
 }

 div.modalDialog {
  width: 600px;
  height:auto;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  top: 10%;
 }

 div.names {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  padding-left: 35px;
 }

 h4 {
  color:#66CCFF;
  text-align:center;
 }

div.variablesType {
  color: #66CCFF;
 float:left;
 padding-left: 45px;
}

div.variablesDiv {
 float: left;
 width: 150px;
 align-content: center;
}

div#variablesContainer {
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 position: relative;
 float:left
}
```

The 6 divs (variables, type, comp1, extern1, coords1 and id1) should be in a line, but I don't know why the overflow does not work.

Comment: What is the behaviour you  are expecting ?@Paul

Comment: You have padding, plus, fixed widths for all 6 divs. All this restricts auto I suppose. So you will have to change any one, either padding or total width.

Comment: Maybe because the widths, combined with padding, etc. are too big for the container?

Comment: Plus you have them floating, which means they'll go to the next line when there isn't enough room.

Comment: I expect that the the divs (variables, type, comp1, extern1, coords1 and id1) are showed in a line and because there is not enough space, it should appear the scroll-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4gp4L/4/)

HTML

```
<div class="modalDialog" id="chooseVariableDialog">
     <h4>Choose Variables</h4>

    <div class="" id="variablesContainer">
        <div class="variablesDivWraper">
            <div class="variablesDiv">
                <div class="variablesType">Variables</div>
            </div>
            <div class="variablesDiv">
                <div class="variablesType">Type</div>
            </div>
            <div class="variablesDiv">
                <div class="variablesType">comp1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="variablesDiv">
                <div class="variablesType">extern1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="variablesDiv">
                <div class="variablesType">coord1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="variablesDiv">
                <div class="variablesType">id1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
var variablesDivCount = $('.variablesDiv').length;
$('.variablesDivWraper').width(variablesDivCount * 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with

```
div#variablesContainer {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    float:left
}
```

By making width: auto you're telling the container to adapt to the width of its parent element, not its content.

Try width: 900px; and it will work.

Comment: with "width: 900px" works for this one, but in my program, by clicking on specific buttons, there will be added a new column (-div) and then won't work anymore with width:900px;
That's why I set width:auto, because I thought, that the container will adapt his width on the width of his children-nodes.

Comment: Then you would need to add callbacks to the buttons triggering such actions; The callback should calculate the new size and set it on the container.

Answer (score 0):

Few css change will make the div scrollable.

1) Remove float:left and add display: table-cell property to div.variablesDiv. You have declared css for variablesDiv in two places. Remove any on of the declaration and use the following css for *div.variablesDiv*

```
div.variablesDiv {
   /*float: left;*/
   width: 150px;
   align-content: center;
   display: table-cell;
}
```

2) Modify overflow property of div.modalDialog to overflow-x: scroll

```
div.modalDialog {
   width: 600px;
   height:auto;
   overflow-x:scroll;
   background-color: #F0F0F0;
   top: 10%;
}
```